# PosgreSQL complains about null 'id'

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am creating some basic BE with Java 17 and Spring Boot 3 and when I try to insert an entry of this type

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    public UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String name;
    public String icon;
}
```

with the following SQL Insert

```
insert into companies(icon, name) values ('icon.png', 'UPV')
```

It complains by saying

```
[23502] ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "companies" violates not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains (null, UPV, icon.png).
```

The tables are being automatically created by JPA in a Docker container that is running locally, just in case that matters. Any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Can you try `@UuidGenerator` ?

Comment: I tried, the exact same error keeps popping up...

Comment: How are you issuing that SQL insert? You have UUID generation which tells your JPA provider to generate the key - it isn't a DB sequence object, you would have to call persist on an entity for it to generate the UUID and include it in the insert statement

Comment: my bet: `@Id` there is from `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` instead of `jakarta.persistence.Id`

Answer (score 0):

You also have to declare `GenericGenerator` that will be used on generation entity UUID.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", type = org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator.class)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String name;
    public String icon;
}
```